# how to giving web application a name to be accessed throughout the world

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, web, server, weblogic-10.x

i can create web applications using J2EE technologies in short a war file, now i want to know how can i give this war file a name like (wwww.mywarfilewebsite.com) most likely a website name. So that this war file can be accessed through out the world from every where. I only know how to deploy war files in webserver like tomcat and application servers like glassfish, weblogic.

Do i have to install another type of webserver like production server ?

or

Do i need to buy a domain from godaddy.com or any one else is it not possible to make a website name without them ?

Comment: is it possible for me create a website from my system and making it available on internet without any extra hardware like router or without buying domain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option will be to buy a domain. If you’re on a budget, there are strategies for buying a cheap domain name. Find a domain name that is easy to remember and easy to spell. If you use domains ending with .com, you will end up with more traffic, but most of the easy ones are taken, so be creative!

Look to Network Solutions, GoDaddy, or Register.com are good in US and uk2.net if you're in the UK to research and find the ideal domain name for your website. Wordpress also includes a feature whereby you can use a name that's tagged with their site, for example, mywebsite.wordpress.com. But if the name you choose is also available as a .com, they will notify you when you sign up.

And finally, choose a web host and upload your website. Your web host may have an FTP feature, or you can download your own FTP program like FileZilla or CyberDuck.

**EDIT** (is it possible to make a globally accessible website without buying domain

The short answer to the question is "yes". But you should really read the long answer.  There are two ways,

**firstly**,  some free web hosts, allow you to create a website even if you don't have a domain name. To do that they create a subdomain which they associate with your website.

For example, if your web host is "example.com" (not a real web host), they may create a subdomain called "mateen.example.com" which you can use for your website. Visitors typing "mateen.example.com" will end up at your website. You don't have to pay for such a subdomain name, since you don't actually own it; the web host owns "example.com" and can create and delete whatever subdomains they wish.

**secondly**, as you are eager to know if you can do it on your own machine with apache-tomcat, it is also possible, but for this YOU NEED TO HAVE A PUBLIC - STATIC IP address. If you have a dedicated public IP address the users from anywhere can access your site with that IP. But giving it a name will not be possible. i.e. if your web-application is at your machine with for example static IP 172.20.55.89 the other users need to use for example 172.20.55.89:8080/application to access it. They cant do like www.mateenwebsite.com since that requires registering a domain. But you need to have a high availability machine for this, for example a workstation at-least (servers are highly recommended).

Further if you want to make a web application globally accessible you can have vpn (virtual private network) facilities. But in that case the intended users also need to be in that vpn group. In both the cases (public-static ip & vpn) you need to pay your ISP and also need a high availability computer.

I guess it helps your doubts now.

Comment: thanks for the answer,but isn't it possible to create a website without buying a domain like creating a website from my own system ? like by using apache 2 server with tomcat or anything like that >

Comment: Thanks alot for answer,   my isp provides me an public ip, earlier i created an webapp and tested it from my mobile by typing the http://ipaddress:port/appname of my application. but as you said if i want to make my war as www.mateenwebsite.com requires a domain registration.    Can i create a domain with registration or do i need to buy domain i will do this at my laptop only for the clients to show the progress of the task that they will give me or some other little things i m not making anything big that i ll give to real world. Sorry for the questions if they are annoying or meaning less.

Comment: they are not annoying or meaningless,it is a conceptual one; i had to discuss with one of my friends who is a web-app pro, it kinda cleared some of my doubts as well.

Comment: i would really appreciate more, if you can also provide me the steps on how to practically create a website from my local system (practical part for the above theory) that is accessible on internet without buying any domain.

Comment: i would still say to go for a high availability hardware though. But do you want to know how to do it using the public-static-ip and your local machine's apache-tomcat service ???

Comment: yes exaclty, so that all the applications i develop my clients can see it on website instead of screen sharing on skype or team viewer